# PHP Using variable within sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My include file includes all of my connection information and I use this for other pages to connect to my database.

I have commented out my working echo line where this shows me the results from my previous page these results come across fine at this point.  The problem I am having is getting the results of my queries to display in line across the page while using the variable from the previous page as the where clause for my SQL statement.  When using this where clause the results will only bring back 1 result.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried adding and removing ' and " to different portions of the query and I am not having any luck.  If necessary I can edit and add the page that shows up before this however currently that information is coming across in the line with the commented code on the predictions.php page.

Below is my includes.php

```
<?php
$dbaddress="localhost";
$dbuser="testuser";
$dbpass="testpass";
$dbname="testdb";
$dbtable="testtable";
$con=mysqli_connect($dbaddress,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)
?>
```

Below is my predictions.php

```
<?
    include 'includes.php';
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $elousera=$_POST['elousera'];
    $elouserb=$_POST['elouserb'];
    #echo 'You selected sequence# '.$elousera.' vs sequence# '.$elouserb;
    $sqla = "SELECT mcacctname FROM $dbtable WHERE Sequence = '$elousera'";
    $resulta = mysqli_query($con,$sqla);
    $playera = mysqli_free_result($resulta);
    $sqlb = "SELECT mcacctname FROM $dbtable WHERE Sequence = '$elouserb'";
    $resultb = mysqli_query($con,$sqlb);
    $playerb = mysqli_free_result($resultb);
    echo 'You selected '.$playera.' vs '.$playerb;
?>
```

Comment: You have never fetched any results from the result set.  `$playera, $playerb` do not contain what you are using them for here. They are `mysqli_result` resource objects.  You need to call `$row_a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($playera);` to get the values back from the SELECT statement.

Comment: That will address the immediate issue. A broader one is the SQL injection vulnerability. Since you are using MySQLi, you ought to be doing so with prepared statements.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Also, what's the point of having a centralized include file which sets up the connection when it doesn't do the error checking afterwards - you're still creating redundant code that way.

Comment: I believe I have the issues corerct that everyone mentions.  I just don't understand the php.net examples for pusing prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_free_result` doesn't actually give you a row from the result.  Consider:

```
    $playera = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta);
    ...
    $playerb = mysqli_fetch_array($resultb);
```

And `$playera['mcacctname']` should give you the result if there is one.  If not, $playera will be null.